# Unable to connect to an AWS Oracle RDS instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm new to working with AWS and RDS.  What I'm trying to do is setup an Oracle DB instance on RDS, that part is fine but when I try to connect to it via an application I get various errors.  Depending on the application I get a couple of different errors.

[Local computer trying to connect to RDS directly]

LinqPad - Connection Error: Server did not respon within the specified timeout interval. (I get this on both the Direct and OCI connection modes)

SQL Developer - IO Error: The network adapter could not establish the connection.

[EC2 instance in same VPC]

LinqPad - Connection Error: NET: Connection was refused with error ORA-12504
(I get this on both the Direct and OCI connection modes also)

I've done some research and it mostly points that the VPC isn't setup correctly, but I'm able to connect to my EC2 instance fine though.

Oddly enough, I did have one fluke incident where from my local computer it did connect, but as soon as I tried the test again I got more errors.

Any help, or new directions to look would be greatly appreciated.
Will provide more information if needed also.  Wasn't sure what to post settings wise.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set up a security group for your RDS instance? If so, are you sure it has the correct IP/CIDR for where you're attempting to connect from?

Comment: I have the RDS set on the same security group as the EC2 instance.

Comment: Tried setting up my security groups according to this site [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html), but still having issues.  I did get an unauthorized indicator on the RDS instance, but fixed that by adding the port to the inbound security group for the RDS.

Comment: I am now able to connect within the VPC on my EC2 instance, but still unable to access the RDS directly from my local computer.  I got this to work by creating a new Routing Table with my subnets associated to it.  Then I routed it to the internet gateway.  Not sure quite why yet why this worked, but I was following this article. [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)